# Codename One Calendar View cannot change Text of current days

Tags: java, calendar, codenameone

I have extended the Calendar in Codename One, however, it seems I couldn't update text for days in the current month, but I can easily update the days that appear before or after the selected month

Image below shows I changed other days to letter "F" :

[image]

Any Ideas where am I missing it, because I tried everything! I am using netbeans, also using the "Chrome" example to test my case.

```
protected com.codename1.ui.Calendar gui_Calendar = new com.codename1.ui.Calendar(){
    @Override protected void setDayText(Component c, String t){
        System.err.println(c+" | "+t);
        super.setDayText(c, "H");
        Button b=(Button)c;
        b.setText("F");
    }
    protected void setDayUIID(Component cmp, String uiid){
    //   System.err.println(cmp+" | "+uiid);
        super.setDayUIID(cmp, uiid);
        
    }
    @Override protected Component createDayComponent(){
        Component c = super.createDayComponent();
        Button b =(Button)c;
        System.err.println("com:" +b+" text:" +b.getText());
        b.setText("GH");
        return c;
    }
    @Override protected Label createDayTitle(int day){
        //this create label for SUMTF
        Label l =super.createDayTitle(day);
        System.err.println("label: "+l.getText()+" d: "+day);
        return l;
    }
    @Override protected String getDayText(Component cmp){
        String s=super.getDayText(cmp);
        System.err.println("TEXT: "+s);
        return s;
    }
    @Override protected void updateButtonDayDate(Component dayButton, int currentMonth, int day){
        System.err.println("dayButton: "+dayButton+ " m: "+currentMonth+ " d: "+day);
        Button b=(Button)dayButton;
        b.setText("M");
        super.updateButtonDayDate(dayButton, currentMonth, day);
    }
    @Override protected void updateButtonDayDate(Component dayButton, int year, int currentMonth, int day){
        System.err.println("dayButton: "+dayButton+ " Y: "+year+" m: "+currentMonth+ " d: "+day);
        Button b=(Button)dayButton;
        b.setText("Y");
        super.updateButtonDayDate(dayButton, currentMonth, day);
    }

};
```

Comment: Why are you invoking `setText ` **before** calling super? If you do it after `super.updateButtonDayDate` it will work. You'd obviously need to include the day information as well when setting the text.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I really dont follow the logic, but it did work, thank you!

Comment: `updateButtonDayDate` in the based class is there to set the text of the button which it does using `setText`. So you invoke `setText` and then `updateButtonDayDate` which internally invokes `setText` again with a different value.

Comment: @shaialmog got it, thank you